# Why does del Toro place his left hand's index finger on his pistol, as he shoots multiple rounds?

Tags: sicario-day-of-the-soldado

The following screenshot hails from the movie *Sicario: Day of the Soldado*, where Benicio del Toro's character puts his left index finger on the pistol as he shoots multiple rounds. I know little of pistols, but  why didn't he merely pull the trigger with his right hand?

[image]

Comment: As an actor he’s known for coming up with unusual quirks for his characters. Like the accent/speech impediment for Finster in *The Usual Suspects* was invented by Del Toro. So my guess is that this is another example. Just something strange to do to make his character more of a character. Contrast with his role in *The Way Of The Gun*.

Comment: @ToddWilcox You might want to flesh these thoughts out into an answer.

Comment: Isn't this supposed to be a way to shoot the gun faster than regular?

Comment: just making new movies moves

Answer (score 4):

It simply allows him to shoot faster. Moving your finger back and forth within the trigger guard is a quicker movement than pulling and releasing a trigger. Try it out the next time you see "Time Crisis" or something similar at the arcade. I imagine the technique works much better with a "virtual gun" like that than with a real pistol, but then that's the only way I've tried it.

Comment: Just FYI, this is a foolish thing to do with a real gun. He's holding a beretta m92f in 9mm. Unless you have hundreds of hours of range time the recoil on a single shot will make that grip stance unstable. If the grip hand should slip, guess where that barrel is going to spin. And with your other hand being a single finger where it should no longer be on a loaded gun with no grip hand, you run the risk of blowing your own face off. Del Toro can do this because they're using underloaded blanks in a muzzle capped prop... or CGI. In short - don't ever try this. It's just for movie flare.

Answer (score 3):

> One of the first operations we see—after the war on the cartels is set in motion—is the hit of a high-level lawyer from one of the organizations. It's done in public, out in the streets of Mexico, by Alejandro.
>
> Dever and crew were able to shut down part of Mexico City so they
> could shoot the scene undisturbed. Del Toro, who grew up with guns, is
> more comfortable than most acting with a firearm in his hands, and
> commands the task as Alejandro. Local actors were brought in to fill
> out the background and coached by Dever, so they could pull off the
> attack properly.
>
> Right before the execution, Alejandro pulls off his ski mask to reveal
> his face, then empties the clip by “bump-firing” his pistol, ***which was
> Del Toro's idea***. The technique involves using your other hand's index
> finger to utilize the gun's recoil for a higher rate of rounds. It's
> been used by gang members for the intimidation factor and ***could be
> seen as a way for Alejandro to make the hit look “sloppy,” which was
> their goal***. The gun was an unmodified Berretta 9mm.

https://www.mensjournal.com/entertainment/josh-brolin-and-benicio-del-toro-on-filming-sicario-day-of-the-soldado